# Wrangling TryWith in Computation expressions

Tags: f#, computation-expression

*(Having failed to 'grok' FParsec, I followed the advice I read somewhere and started trying to write a little parser myself. Somehow I spotted what looked like a chance to try and monadify it, and now I have N problems...)*

This is my 'Result' type (simplified)

```
type Result<'a> = 
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string
```

Here's the computation expression builder

```
type ResultBuilder() =
    member m.Return a = Success(a)
    member m.Bind(r,fn) =
        match r with
        | Success(a) -> fn a
        | Failure(m) -> Failure(m)
```

In this first example, everything works (compiles) as expected:

```
module Parser = 
    let res = ResultBuilder()

    let Combine p1 p2 fn = 
        fun a -> res { let! x = p1 a
                       let! y = p2 a
                       return fn(x,y) }
```

My problem is here: I'd like to be able to catch any failure in the 'combining' function and return a failure, but it says that I should define a 'Zero'.

```
    let Combine2 p1 p2 fn =
        fun a -> res { let! x = p1 a
                       let! y = p2 a
                       try
                          return fn(x,y) 
                       with
                         | ex -> Failure(ex.Message) }
```

Having no idea what I should return in a Zero, I just threw in `member m.Zero() = Failure("hello world")`, and it now says I need `TryWith`.

So:

```
member m.TryWith(r,fn) =
    try 
        r()
    with
     | ex -> fn ex
```

And now it wants Delay, so `member m.Delay f = (fun () -> f())`.

At which point it says (on the `ex -> Failure`), `This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'Result<'a>'`, and I throw up my arms and turn to you guys...

Link for playing: http://dotnetfiddle.net/Ho1sGS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `with` block should also return a result from the computation expression. Since you want to return Result.Failure you need to define the member `m.ReturnFrom a = a` and use it to return the Failure from the `with` block. In the `try` block you should also specify that `fn` returns Success if it doesn't throw.

```
let Combine2 p1 p2 fn =
            fun a -> res { let! x = p1 a
                           let! y = p2 a
                           return! 
                                try
                                    Success(fn(x,y))
                                with
                                    | ex -> Failure(ex.Message)
                         }
```

**Update:**

The original implementation was showing a warning, not an error. The expression in the `with` block was not used since you returned from the `try` block, so you could simply add `|> ignore`. In that case if `fn` throws then the return value is `m.Zero()` and the only difference is that you would get `"hello world"` instead of `ex.Message`. Illustrated with an example below. Full script here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/mFbeZg

Original implementation with `|> ignore` to mute the warning:

```
let Combine3 p1 p2 fn =
            fun a -> res { let! x = p1 a
                           let! y = p2 a

                           try
                                return fn(x,y)
                           with
                                | ex -> Failure(ex.Message) |> ignore // no warning
                         }
```

Run it:

```
let comb2 a  =
    let p1' x = Success(x)
    let p2' y = Success(y)
    let fn' (x,y) = 1/0 // div by zero
    let func = Parser.Combine2 p1' p2' fn' a
    func()

let comb3 a  =
    let p1' x = Success(x)
    let p2' y = Success(y)
    let fn' (x,y) = 1/0 // div by zero
    let func = Parser.Combine3 p1' p2' fn' a
    func()

let test2 = comb2 1
let test3 = comb3 1
```

Result:

```
val test2 : Result<int> = Failure "Attempted to divide by zero."
val test3 : Result<int> = Failure "hello world"
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the ReturnFrom that I was missing! (I guess I then need to decide whether fn returns an `'a` or a `Result<'a>`...)

Comment: Thanks for accepting this! Please see the last edit where `return!` is before `try/with` not two times inside. If `fn` returns `Result<'a>` then you could make all exception logic inside it and do not wrap it into `Success()` but you will still need ReturnFrom method to return the result of the modified `fn`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to support `try` ... `with` inside a computation builder, you need to add `TryWith` (as you tried) as well as a few other members including `Delay` and `Run` (depending on how you want to implement `Delay`). In order to be able to return failure, you also need to support `return!` by adding `ReturnFrom`:

```
type ResultBuilder() =
    member m.Return a = Success(a)
    member m.Bind(r,fn) =
        match r with
        | Success(a) -> fn a
        | Failure(m) -> Failure(m)
    member m.TryWith(r,fn) =
      try r() with ex -> fn ex
    member m.Delay(f) = f
    member m.Run(f) = f()
    member m.ReturnFrom(r) = r
```

Now you can do the following:

```
let Combine2 p1 p2 fn = fun a -> res {  
  let! x = p1 a
  let! y = p2 a
  try
    return fn(x,y) 
  with ex ->
    return! Failure(ex.Message) }
```

The trick is that the normal branch uses just `return` (representing success), but the exception handler uses `return!` to return an explicitly created result using `Failure`.

That said, if you are interested in parsers, then you need to use a different type - what you are describing here is more like the option (or Maybe) monad. To implement parser combinators you need a type that represents *a parser* rather than *result* of  a parser. See for example [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235221/Monadic-Parsing-in-Fsharp).

Comment: Thanks for that. I think my brain isn't quite up to monadic parsers yet. And the monadic result is working ok for me at the moment. Maybe later.