# Statically resolved types member constraints fail to recognize augmentations of system types

Tags: f#, inline

On my quest to get better at F# and gain a better understanding on how Suave.io works, I've been attempting to create some reusable functions/operators for composing functions. I understand that Suave actually implements its >=> operator to work specifically for async option, but I thought I would be fun to try and generalize it.

The code below is inspired by too many sources to credit, and it works well for types I define myself, but I can't make it work for system types. Even though the type augmentations of Nullable and Option compiles fine, they aren't recognized as matching the member constraint in the bind function.

When I failed to make it work for Option, I had hoped that it might be due to Option being special in F#, which is why I tried with Nullable, but sadly, no cigar.

The relevant errors and output from fsi is in the code below in the comment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
John

```
open System

let inline bind (f : ^f) (v : ^v) =
   (^v : (static member doBind : ^f * ^v -> ^r )(f, v))
    // I'd prefer not having to use a tuple in doBind, but I've
    // been unable to make multi arg member constraint work

let inline (>=>) f g = f >> (bind g)

// Example with Result 
type public Result<'a,'b> = 
    | Success of 'a 
    | Error of 'b

type public Result<'a,'b> with
    static member inline public doBind (f, v) = 
        match v with
        | Success s -> f s
        | Error e -> Error e

let rF a = if a > 0 then Success a else Error "less than 0"
let rG a = if a < 10 then Success a else Error "greater than 9"

let rFG = rF >=> rG
// val rFG : (int -> Result<int,string>)

//> rFG 0;;
//val it : Result<int,string> = Error "less than 0"
//> rFG 1;;
//val it : Result<int,string> = Success 1
//> rFG 10;;
//val it : Result<int,string> = Error "greater than 9"
//> rFG 9;;
//val it : Result<int,string> = Success 9

// So it works as expected for Result

// Example with Nullable

type Nullable<'T when 'T: (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T: struct and 'T:> ValueType> with
    static member inline public doBind (f, v: Nullable<'T>) = 
        if v.HasValue then f v.Value else Nullable()

let nF a = if a > 0 then Nullable a else Nullable()
let nG a = if a < 10 then Nullable a else Nullable()
let nFG = nF >=> nG
// error FS0001: The type 'Nullable<int>' does not support the operator 'doBind'


type Core.Option<'T> with
    static member inline doBind (f, v) = 
        match v with
        | Some s -> f s
        | None -> None


let oF a = if a > 0 then Some a else None
let oG a = if a < 10 then Some a else None

let oFG = oF >=> oG
// error FS0001: The type 'int option' does not support the operator 'doBind'
```

Comment: Extension members aren't considered for statically resolved type constraints. Just not a feature of F#, period. [Please cast your vote on uservoice](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5664242-simulate-higher-kinded-polymorphism).

Comment: As Fyodor mentioned, this is not supported. While I think this would actually be a nice extension to F#, I'm kind of curious about what use cases you had mind for this? I find Suave nice because it is quite simple and not overly abstract, so generalizing the operators does not sound like something that would go towards better F# code - though it's fun to just explore it, of course.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thanks, that explains it. What an annoying limitation, 3 votes have been cast :)

Comment: @TomasPetricek No use case yet, just playing. Back in my C++ days I used templates to their full extent, mostly to good effect. I particularly enjoyed using Loki, which kinda took things to their limits. I've always been a little annoyed by generics in C#, they lack power, so I am/was hoping that F# might rectify that.

Comment: @JJJ I'm not sure - you can stretch the F# static constraints a bit (like FsControl does), but I don't think it's what they're designed for. _[rant] FsControl is amazing achievemnt, but I would not really use it in practice, because it gets close to the rough edges - and there is usually more idiomatic solution to the original problem. In other words, I think taking concepts from one language (C++ templates or Haskell type classes) and trying to use them in another language (F#) does not always lead to very clean code. [/rant]_

Comment: @TomasPetricek Don't worry, I'm a pragmatic guy. I just enjoy exploring the language. Maybe if F# had a stronger, more consistent story for meta-programming, people wouldn't try to bring in stuff from everywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why extension methods are not taken into account in static member constraints is a question that has been asked many times and surely it will continue being asked until that feature is implemented in the F# compiler.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071645/error-on-extension-methods-when-inlining/38071927#38071927) with a link to other related questions and a link to a detailed explanation of what has to be done in the F# compiler in order to support this feature.

Now for your specific case the workaround mentioned there solves you issue and it's already implemented in [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl).

Here's the code:

```
#nowarn "3186"
#r "FsControl.dll"

open FsControl.Operators

// Example with Result 
type public Result<'a,'b> = 
    | Success of 'a 
    | Error of 'b

type public Result<'a,'b> with
    static member Return v = Success v
    static member Bind (v, f) = 
        match v with
        | Success s -> f s
        | Error e -> Error e

let rF a = if a > 0 then Success a else Error "less than 0"
let rG a = if a < 10 then Success a else Error "greater than 9"

let rFG = rF >=> rG
// val rFG : (int -> Result<int,string>)

rFG 0
//val it : Result<int,string> = Error "less than 0"
rFG 1
//val it : Result<int,string> = Success 1
rFG 10
//val it : Result<int,string> = Error "greater than 9"
rFG 9
//val it : Result<int,string> = Success 9

// So it works as expected for Result


// Example with Option

let oF a = if a > 0 then Some a else None
// val oF : a:int -> int option

let oG a = if a < 10 then Some a else None
// val oG : a:int -> int option

let oFG = oF >=> oG
// val oFG : (int -> int option)

oFG 0
// val it : int option = None

oFG 1
// val it : int option = Some 1
```

Anyway I would recommend using existing `Choice` instead of Success/Error or [implementing Success on top of Choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411297/building-either-or-result-on-top-of-choice-in-f/28412601#28412601) in your case it would be like this:

```
type Result<'a, 'b> = Choice<'a, 'b>
let  Success x :Result<'a, 'b> = Choice1Of2 x
let  Error   x :Result<'a, 'b> = Choice2Of2 x
let  (|Success|Error|) = function Choice1Of2 x -> Success x | Choice2Of2 x -> Error x
```

And then you can run your examples without writing any bind or return.

You might wonder why there is no example for `Nullable`, well that's simply because `Nullable` is not a monad, it only works on value types and a function is not a value type so better stick to `Option` for the same functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll check out the links and FsControl in particular.

Comment: @JJJ In fact you don't even need to implement Success on top of Choice (see the updated answer).
Anyway that's certainly a good idea, because you'll reuse all existing functionality and increase compatibility with other libraries.